# Unity WebGL canvas lost focus when click on iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, unity-game-engine

I'm using `iframe` that consist button `onclick="set_permanent()"` , the problem is the main canvas lost focus every time i click any button on `iframe`.

```
function set_permanent(){
    SendMessage("Manager","Permanent_SetTooth");
}
```

after that i found the way to fix it by manually set the focus to the iframe's parent

```
function set_permanent(){
    SendMessage("Manager","Permanent_SetTooth");
    parent.focus();
}
```

let say i have so many function to add more, means i need to add `parent.focus()` on the end of every function, is there any way to modify default behavior of `onclick` or maybe automatically focus on parent after loosing focus? so i don't need to add `parent.focus()` on every function.